# Are there special permissions needed to use the crypto class?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a routine using crypto class to encrypt data and store is a custom field.
This routine is working fine as long as I am logged in as an administrator.
when I login in as another user the data is not saved.
Are there special permissions needed to use the crypto class?
The myStr is a 32 character hidden strign;
the enir routin is here:

```
        Blob key = Blob.valueOf(myStr);
        Blob cipherText = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, val);
        String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText); 
        System.debug(encodedCipherText);
        ld.z_encodedFEIN__c = encodedCipherText;            
        update ld;
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! No, there's no special permission required to call Crypto methods (or any Apex code). If it's failing, perhaps there's a sharing error? Some more surrounding context would be useful for us to help you out. Please read about [ask].

Comment: Check if 'Customize Application' and 'Manage Encryption Keys' permissions are enabled under 'Administrative Permissions' on profile.